# how to set border for inner and outer element to prevent double border in besides

Tags: css

i know we can use `inset` and `ouset` border to styling border for a table.

```
table{border: 1px inset #fff;}
td{border: 1px outset #fff;}
```

everything is OK when we are using table because every thing is in a `td` and you never put an element or text in the `table` tag directly.

now the question is that when we are using `div`s to do the same styling there are many problems.

1. if we put a text or element in outer div we don't see any border in right side of it.
2. first inner `div` hast not border in top.

here is the fiddle to make the problem more specific.
http://jsfiddle.net/v4D9q/

Answer (score 1):

Do you have to use inset/outset?

It's a few lines more css, but why not just put a border on the top/left/right of the outer, and only set border bottom on the inner elements.

HTML:

```
<div class="outer">
    outer div (we dont see border in right side)
    <div class="inner">inner div</div>
    <div class="inner">inner div</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.outer{
    border-left: 1px solid #000;
    border-right: 1px solid #000;
    border-top: 1px solid #000;                
}
.inner{
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000; 
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/PFhfF/

Comment: Use a light color for top/left and darker color for bottom/right border to get an embossed effect.

Comment: If you try this: [http://jsfiddle.net/NeF8D/](http://jsfiddle.net/NeF8D/) , even when there are no inner elements, you will have a complete border, and no need for any first elements