# How to prevent double border in tr > td element

Tags: css, border

I would like to know if is possible to prevent double borders in a `tr > td` element. If I use `border:1px solid #DDD` then the first element will have all borders and then the second one too but because the first has a border-right and the second has a border-left then the borders are double and the same happens for the second tr where first has border-bottom and second has border-top. Any tips? I see this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10927216/how-to-set-border-for-inner-and-outer-element-to-prevent-double-border-in-beside) but won't work for me because is for DIV and I'm using tables.

Comment: What does your HTML and CSS look like?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Start with:

`border-collapse:collapse;`

and then tune as necessary.  Using the `:first-child` and `:last-child` pseudo selectors can be used to modify default styling on one end.

Comment: Matt it works just only setting up `border-collapse: collpase;` as you and Ryan suggested but I'll like to view a example of what you're saying about tune. Is much to ask to write a little example?

Comment: If `border-collapse` does the trick then you don't need to worry about it, but the pseudo selectors would be for more customized behavior.  As a contrived example if you wanted to have one row with a different color vertical border between the cells only (and not on the table border), then you could do something like `tr.special > td { border-right-color: #f00; } tr.special > td:last-child { border-right-color: #000; }`

Comment: Has to be applied to the `table { border-collapse:collapse; }` element, & not at the cell (th,td) levels.

Answer (score 8):

Instead of putting borders on the cells, set a background color on the table itself to the color you want the borders to be, then space the cells by 1px:

HTML:

```
​<table>
    <tr>
        <td>One</td>
        <td>Two</td>
        <td>Three</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Four</td>
        <td>Five</td>
        <td>Six</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
table {
    background: #ccc;
    border-spacing: 1px;
}
td {
    background: #fff;
    padding: 5px;
}
```

That will give you this:

[image: cellspacing example]

Note that you have to set a background color on the cells themselves, too, otherwise the background color of the table will show through.

Comment: While this works, it is kinda hacky, and not ideal if the design requires different backgrounds, or semi-transparent backgrounds.

Comment: This is exceedingly hacky and it obfuscates the intent of the design: particularly when the standard accepted way to do it is so readily available.

Comment: Exceedingly hacky? Why? It's perfectly valid, it achieves the intended effect, and it will even work in browsers that don't support `:first-child` and `:last-child`. I don't see the harm.

Comment: without going into the debate of ideal or not, no doubt it's one of the easiest solutions. just for the sake of better understandability, use `background: white;` for th, td, and any darker background color for table

Answer (score 6):

You're looking for [border-collapse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/border-collapse)

> The border-collapse CSS property selects a table's border model. This has a big influence on the look and style of the table cells.

Values are as such.

```
border-collapse:  collapse | separate | inherit
```

Comment: Thx don't know what the property really means until now.

Answer (score 0):

For those of you who previous answers didn't work, I used table {border-spacing: -2px;} (works for mPDF)